# bpel rest adapter json output and utf-8 charcters

Tags: oracle, rest, web-services, utf-8, bpel

I have a BPEL Web Service. when I set the output type to XML , it has no problem and the utf-8 characters are working well. but when I set the output type  to json, the utf-8 parts of the result goes wrong :

```
{
name :'Ø§Ø±Ø³Øª',
Code:12544,
Country: 'China',
Adress : 'Sian Street'
}
```

any suggestion to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: `Countery` & `Ø§Ø±Ø³Øª`  ???

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan no, only name has utf-8 character.